# How to create a shopping cart rule - Get an certain item free if you spend over $50

Tags: cart, coupon, shopping

How do I create a shopping cart rule where you get an item free if you spend over $50? I do not want to download any extensions, I just need to know how to make a certain item free when customers spend over $50.

The actual "free" item is over $50 in value and when it is in the shopping cart with an item that is lets say $5 its still allowing the rule to run since the total is over $50 even though the customer isn't actually spending over $50.

Comment: What do your current rules look like?

Answer (score 5):

You'll want your rule to match both of these conditions:

- The cart contains $50+ of other products
- The cart contains at least one of those "free" items

Here's a screenshot of what the rule should look like:

[image: Screenshot of the rule configuration]

Change `GIFT` to whatever SKU your "free" product uses.

Comment: Also at the action tab you need to add 100% discount on Gift sku

Comment: I know this is an old question, but i don't see "total amount" in my dropdown.

Comment: @Supplement stumbled upon this in search and just wanted to answer you question for anyone else.  You select `Product Subselection` and then click `Total Quantity`. From there it gives you the option to switch to `Total Amount`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to do it this way. When I tried the suggested answer, it timed out when trying to apply the coupon.

[image]